# Optimization of double subtraction in C++

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I have the following code that I use to compute the distance between two vectors:

```
double dist(vector<double> & vecA, vector<double> & vecB){
    double curDist = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vecA.size(); i++){
        double dif = vecA[i] - vecB[i];
        curDist += dif * dif;
    }

    return curDist;
}
```

This function is a major bottleneck in my application since it relies on a lot of distance calculations, consuming more than 60% of CPU time on a typical input. Additionally, the following line:

```
double dif = vecA[i] - vecB[i];
```

is responsible for more than 77% of CPU time in this function. My question is: is it possible to somehow optimize this function?

Notes:

- To profile my application I have used Intel Amplifier XE;
- Reducing the number of distance computations is not a feasible solution for
  me;

Comment: If that line really takes more than half the CPU time, it would seem to be cache related (ie first access to each element takes a cache hit) and not really easily optimized by speeding up code. You may need to look into vector based instructions to alleviate that a bit (a'la SSE3)

Comment: @Mystical the vector.size() vary between 4 to 100 depending on the application input (i.e. dataset dimensionality).

Comment: Is this the STL's vector? Would be a shame if all the people here assume it is and it isn't.

Comment: Is this functionality actually called distance?  I know if (instead of `vecB`) one used the mean of `vecA`, this would be the standard of deviation.

Comment: Do you get the same performance if you pass a reference to hold the return value? You save declaring the local variable and copying the result. Also, vecA[i] has to compute with another add the base + i to get to the value you want to retrieve. Instead, use an iterator that you increment.

Comment: @ Mooing duck - it also computes the square of the distance between two points represented as coordinate vectors.

Comment: Have you single-stepped the loop, one instruction at a time, to make sure it's not calling hidden functions or bounds-checking?

Comment: @eznme Yes it is a standard library vector (i.e. std::vector).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible issues I can think of right now:

- This computation is memory bound.
- There is an iteration-to-iteration dependency on `curDist`.

---

**This computation is memory bound.**

Your dataset is larger than your CPU cache. So in this case, no amount of optimization is going to help unless you can restructure your algorithm.

---

**There is an iteration-to-iteration dependency on `curDist`.**

You have a dependency on `curDist`. This will block vectorization by the compiler. (Also, don't always trust the profiler numbers to the line. They can be inaccurate especially after compiler optimizations.)

Normally, the compiler vectorizer can split up the `curDist` into multiple partial sums to and unroll/vectorize the loop. But it can't do that under strict-floating-point behavior. You can try relaxing your floating-point mode if you haven't already. Or you can split the sum and unroll it yourself.

For example, this kind of optimization is something the compiler can do with integers, **but not necessarily with floating-point**:

```
double curDist0 = 0.0;
double curDist1 = 0.0;
double curDist2 = 0.0;
double curDist3 = 0.0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vecA.size() - 3; i += 4){
    double dif0 = vecA[i + 0] - vecB[i + 0];
    double dif1 = vecA[i + 1] - vecB[i + 1];
    double dif2 = vecA[i + 2] - vecB[i + 2];
    double dif3 = vecA[i + 3] - vecB[i + 3];
    curDist0 += dif0 * dif0;
    curDist1 += dif1 * dif1;
    curDist2 += dif2 * dif2;
    curDist3 += dif3 * dif3;
}

//  Do some sort of cleanup in case (vecA.size() % 4 != 0)

double curDist = curDist0 + curDist1 + curDist2 + curDist3;
```

Comment: I see you're using Visual Studio C++ 2010. That compiler doesn't support vectorization yet... You might get better performance with ICC or GCC.

Comment: may want to check your for loop there... ;)

Comment: @Nim Thanks for catching that. :)

Comment: Good answer! You need i+=4 and then just add the original loop for the last (up to 3 steps) starting from where the unrolled one left.

Comment: @MooingDuck I usually just duplicate the original loop. But in nearly all my applications, I can force the dataset to a multiple of some power-of-two, so I don't have the issue in the first place. To be truely efficient, you need some startup code to align the data before entering a fully unrolled+vectorized loop.

Comment: A switch is slower, but doesn't violate the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle.  Personal preference.  In either case: I expect to see LOTS OF COMMENTS INCLUDING BEFORE AND AFTER TIMINGS if you unroll a loop.

Comment: [performance testing](http://ideone.com/j1yn5):  Changing vectors to `const` got a 4% increase, unrolling got a 12% additional increase.  Don't use a switch.

Answer (score 3):

You could eliminate the call to `vecA.size()` for each iteration of the loop, just call it once before the loop.  You could also do loop unrolling to give yourself more computation per loop iteration.  What compiler are you using, and what optimization settings?  Compiler will often do unrolling for you, but you could manually do it.

Comment: Beat me to the `vecA.size()` by mere moments. The compiler may or may not be able to determine that this value will remain constant for the during of the loop, so it may not be able to optimize it out. Loop unrolling is another good idea.

Comment: Actually, `vector::size` is a constant-time operation and the compiler should be able to inline it and optimize it away...

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2010 with default parameters. Please note that the profiler's results shows that vecA.size() does not consume a significant part of CPU time.

Comment: "constant-time" doesn't mean it's as fast as a local variable access that's likely sitting in a register.  Compiler can't guarantee that vector::size will remain constant through the loop.  But if you had a local var that you put the size in, compiler would know the value can't change

Comment: @TJD You were right: eliminating the call to vecA.size() did reduce the overall CPU time. Now my next step is to solve the subtraction line problem, which is the major bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

If it's feasible (if the range of the numbers isn't huge) you may want to explore using fixed point to store these numbers, rather than doubles.

Fixed point would turn these into int operations rather than double operations.

Another interesting thing is that assuming your profile is correct, the lookups seems to be a significant factor (otherwise the multiplication would likely be more costly than the subtractions).

I'd try using a const vector iterator rather than the random access lookup. It may help in two ways: 1 - it is constant, and 2 - the serial nature of the iterator may let the processor do better caching.

Comment: You either need to use a library or implement it yourself. There's plenty of info on stackoverflow if you search for it.

Answer (score 0):

If your platform does not have (or is not using) an ALU that supports floating point math, floating point libraries, by nature, are slow and consume additional non-volatile memory.  I suggest instead using 32-bit (`long`) or 64-bit (`long long`) fixed-point arithmetic.  Then convert the final result to floating point at the end of the algorithm.  I did this on a project a couple years ago to improve the performance of an I2T algorithm and it worked wonderfully.